# How to Declare Dynamic Variable name in LaTeX?

Tags: macros

I want to include multiple latex files in main file. In each file there will be variable names as like this

```
\filenameXXX
```

where

> filename

is the name of the file and XXX is integral part of the variable name and XXX will be some letters.

for example if I include file name myFirstfile.tex, the variable name will be

```
\myFirstfileXXX
```

and so on.

My question is how to do this without defining this explicitly. I want to get the file name in the variable with a command.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is `XXX` supposed to be? Numbers? Letters? Your question as it stands right now is a little bit unclear

Comment: It will be letters.

Comment: it is clearly possible for `myFirstfile.tex` to have a definition of `\myFirstfileXXX` but what is your question? what do you want to define the command to be?

Comment: My question is how to do this without defining this explicitly. I want to get the file name in the variable with a command.

Comment: @molam41: How do you include these files in your main document?

Comment: why do you want the filename to be the _name_ of the command rather than its definition? What do you want the definition of `\myFirstfileXXX` to be. I  really suggest that you edit the question it is not clear enough to answer (even though an answer has been attempted)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand you want to be able to define a command where some parts are dynamically generated. To do this you need the commands `\csname` and `\endcsname`. Anything that is given in between those is interpreted as a command. For example, instead of writing `\LaTeX` you can write

```
\csname LaTeX\endcsname
```

This can be used in a command definition, but then you need to take care so you don't try to redfine `\csname` it self, and for this you need `\expandafter`. For example

```
\newcommand\SomeLetters{ABC}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname MyFirstFile\SomeLetters\endcsname{---Output from MyFirstFile---}
```

will define a command `\MyFirstFileABC`. To get the file name you can use `\jobname`. In my case I use the file `Test.tex` and then

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname\jobname\SomeLetters\endcsname{---Output from jobname command---}
```

will define the command `\TestABC`.

If you then want to define a new command with inputs, and using your dynamic command name you can do something like

```
\newcommand\mycommandgenerator[3]{% {Basename}{Postfix}{Number inputs}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1#2\endcsname[#3]}
\mycommandgenerator{Name}{abc}{1}{**#1**}
```

Then by using `\mycommandgenerator` you can define a new command with the name consisting of the first and second inputs. The third input specifies the number of inputs to your new command. In this case the definition of `\Nameabc` is equivalent to

```
\newcommand\Nameabc[1]{**#1**}
```

You can even use non-letters in the command name, but then you need to use `\csname` and `\endcsname` to use it. The command

```
\mycommandgenerator{AB34}{XYZ}{0}{My command output}
```

defines a command with the name `AB34XYZ` but since numbers are not allowed in names it must be called with `\csname AB34XYZ\endcsname`.

The whole example is given as the file `Test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\SomeLetters{ABC}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname MyFirstFile\SomeLetters\endcsname{---Output from MyFirstFile---}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname\jobname\SomeLetters\endcsname{---Output from jobname command---}
\newcommand\mycommandgenerator[3]{% {Basename}{Postfix}{Number inputs}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1#2\endcsname[#3]}
\mycommandgenerator{Name}{abc}{1}{**#1**}
\mycommandgenerator{AB34}{XYZ}{0}{My command output}
\begin{document}
\csname LaTeX\endcsname

.\MyFirstFileABC.

.\TestABC.

.\Nameabc{hjk}.

.\csname AB34XYZ\endcsname.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: @molam41 Welcome to TeX.SE! The way to say thank StefanH is by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Yes, the answer is up-voted.