# Using dynamic variables within dynamic variables

Tags: variable, csname

I was looking at the examples at:
[How to Declare Dynamic Variable name in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369104/how-to-declare-dynamic-variable-name-in-latex)
and
[Dynamic Conditional Variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402611/dynamic-conditional-variables)

And I still seem to be getting errors when I try to create dynamic variables. Here's a minimal (failing) example and I think this should help show what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}                                                                           
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%
% Create a variable
% And a subscript with that variable
\newcommand\mypartialordergenerator[2]{% {Basename}{subscript}
    \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator{\csname #1\endcsname}{#2}
    \expandafter\newcommand{\csname #1 A\endcsname}{A_{\csname #1\endcsname}}
}

%%%
% Should create
%
% \DeclareMathOperator{\para}{PARA}
% \newcommand{\paraA}{A_{\para}}
\mypartialordergenerator{para}{PARA}

\begin{document}

    Neither \para nor \paraA works =/

\end{document}
```

I think basically I am doing something bad with the `\expandafter` commands. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\expandafter\DeclareMathOperator{
```

tries to expand `{` and obviously doesn't succeed. You need to expand `\csname` instead. Just remove those braces.

Also the space between `#1` and `A` should be removed.

```
\newcommand\mypartialordergenerator[2]{% {Basename}{subscript}
    \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1A\endcsname{A_{\csname #1\endcsname}}%
}
```

Comment: I had tried that and it only ended up defining `\para` with your updated method, it still fails to load `\paraA` which is where I'm mainly confused. Even with the `\expandafter` no variable `\paraA` is being created. I'm gonna test things out and see what works. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @AramPapazian Oh, sorry! I didn't notice the space between `#1` and `A`! Remove it!

Comment: No worries! That works perfectly =) So another question, why is it that I need `\expandafter` for the first `\csname ...` but not the second one for `paraA`? It seems like that one should need it too?

Comment: @AramPapazian You need `\expandafter` in order to present `\DeclareMathOperator` or `\newcommand` an already formed control sequence token, otherwise they'd try to define `\csname`. In the body of `\paraA` you just need to use `\para` and it's equivalent to call it by `\csname para\endcsname`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @egreg! You're awesome as always.